# Processing XML without loading entire document in memory?

Tags: .net, xml

I'm looking for a .NET XPathNavigator that can read XML without loading the entire document in memory (which is what XPathDocument does). Is there a class that does this, or do I have to write my own?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [System.Xml.XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) if you want to read in a stream.

I don't know of an XPathNavigator that navigates on a XML stream.
you may have to build that.

You could call it AmnesiacXPathNavigator, because it would have to read through the stream anew, for every xpath query you evaluate on it.