# How to work with an Xml file without loading the whole document in memory?

Tags: c#, xml

How to add a new node, update an existing node and remove an existing node of an xml document without loading the whole document in memory?

I'm having an xml document and treating it as the memory of my application so would need to be able to do hundreds of reads and writes quickly without loading the whole document.

its structure is like this:

```
<spiderMemory>
  <profileSite profileId="" siteId="">
    <links>
      <link>
        <originalUrl></originalUrl>
        <isCrawled></isCrawled>
        <isBroken></isBroken>
        <isHtmlPage></isHtmlPage>
        <firstAppearedLevel></firstAppearedLevel>
      </link>
    </links>
  </profileSite>
</spiderMemory>
```

How would that be possible with XDocument?

Thanks

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797167/processing-xml-without-loading-entire-document-in-memory

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do hundreds of reads and writes quickly... you might be using the wrong technology. Have you tried using a plain old RDBMS?

If you still need the XML representation, then you can create an export methods to produce it from the database.

XML isn't really a good substitute for this kind of problem. Just saying.

Also... what is wrong with having the whole thing in memory? How big can it possibly get? Say 1GB? Suck it up. Say 1TB? Oops. But then XML is wrong, wrong, wrong anyway in that case ;) way too verbose!

Comment: thanks. I can't create a separate database for this and if I use the existing prod one, thousands of requests slow the database down for the production users.

Comment: the first version of the app used memory and we have 200 combinations of sites and profiles each which should be crawled up to 20 inner levels so you can imagine it went up quickly to GBs of RAM.

Comment: you won't be happy ever doing this in xml. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XmlReader, something like this :

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Open);
XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
while(reader.Read())
{
  Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
}
```

here is an more elaborate example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As Daren Thomas said, the proper solution is to use RDBMS instead of XML for your needs. I have a partial solution using XML and Java. **Stax parser** does not parse the whole document in memory and is a lot faster than DOM (still XML parsing will always be slow). A 'pull parser' (eg Stax)  allows u to control what gets parsed. A less cleaner way is to throw an exception in SAX parser when you get the element(s) needed.

To modify, the simplest (but slow) way is to use XPath. Another (untested) option is to treat XML file as **text** and then **'Search and replace'** stuff. Here you can use all kinds of text search optimization.